# How to shear an image array?

Tags: arrays, image, transformation

I wanted to shear my image array using python.
What I mean by shear is:

```
x_sheared = (1 + gamma1) * X + gamma2 * Y
y_sheared = gamma2 * X + (1 - gamma1) * Y
```

or, this is the shear matrix

```
shear matrix = [1+gamm1, gamma2,
                gamma2, 1-gamma1]
```

Ok. This is what shear looks like in practice:
[image: Galaxy1: Original Galaxy, SG1: gamma1=0.03, gamma2 =0.02]
or
[image: Cosmic Shear]
This definition of shear is slightly different.

Given that I have an image array that is defined by this:

```
def generateGalaxy(num_points, size, r_disk, f_brightness_ratio, r_bulge):
# generate grid
x = np.arange(-size/2, size/2)
y = np.arange(-size/2, size/2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
r = (X**2 + Y**2)**0.5
# generate random points
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_points)
r = np.random.uniform(0, 10, num_points)

#find the x & y coordinates of these randoms points
x_rand = r * np.cos(theta)
y_rand = r * np.sin(theta)
r_rand = np.sqrt(x_rand**2 + y_rand**2)

values = 1

# generate blank image
mask_xy = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.uint8)
# print(mask_xy[32][30])

# generate galaxy image
mask_xy[y_rand.astype(int) + size//2, x_rand.astype(int) + size//2] = values

return mask_xy

InitialGalaxy1= generateGalaxy(num_points, size, r_disk, f_brightness_ratio, r_bulge)
```

or this:

```
InitialGalaxy001 = rotate(InitialGalaxy1, angle=45, reshape=False)
```

How do I apply shear to the image array?
[image: Here are my original and rotated image arrays]

This is how I originally applied shear. I make the generateGalaxy function also return `x_rand, y_rand`, and pass them to the shear function:

```
def shearGalaxy(gamma1, gamma2, X, Y, size):
# set the shear values
gamma1 = gamma1
gamma2 = gamma2

# doing the shear transformation
x_sheared = (1 + gamma1) * X + gamma2 * Y
y_sheared = gamma2 * X + (1 - gamma1) * Y
r = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
r_sheared = np.sqrt(x_sheared**2 + y_sheared**2)

values = 1

# generate image
mask_xy_sheared = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.uint8)
mask_xy_sheared[y_sheared.astype(int) + size//2, x_sheared.astype(int) + size//2] = values
return mask_xy_sheared
```

However, I think this is too complicated. Is there a way to shear the image without having to know `x_rand, y_rand`?